Ruby's Net::SSH is limited to 3 authentication tries while OpenSSH client is not
I'm having a really weird problem where when I connect to an SSH server (that has a pretty standard default configuration, including a default MaxAuthTries of 6) using Net::SSH, the connection fails after 3 authentication attempts with a disconnected: Too many authentication failures (2) (Net::SSH::Disconnect) exception while the OpenSSH command line client connects fine.
The problem is that my SSH Agent already knows about 4 identities and offers them automatically - annoyingly before the identity that is configured in the SSH client configuration file for that server - and so the OpenSSH client always succeeds to connect and the Net::SSH client always fails to connect. I can get the Net::SSH client to connect by disabling the SSH Agent.
My setup:
$ ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:fMBMXD1mpUpM/vmVcjaXDvdIvPy4GCCdG5lc8ga1cLU /home/odeda/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
3072 SHA256:nfsiFP9APVl6oOK5htpldBmknVTDt1lCLvuHpTaaAao odeda@vesho (RSA)
2048 SHA256:t3+SY5Ru+tJ3r/HE7qIW4fnXswQ16btCiIadVGa2XPM odeda@jior (RSA)
1024 SHA256:EKBzRjDE6twnRLlIT3IHEfu08tVXCSK1henMHB+s+p8  (DSA)
$ grep example.com ~/.ssh/config -A1
Host *.example.com
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_example_identity.pem

Running Net::SSH
$ bundle exec ruby -rnet/ssh -e 'Net::SSH.start("server.example.com","ubuntu",{
  host_name:"3.456.789.12",
  verify_host_key: :never,
  user_known_hosts_file: "/dev/null",
  non_interactive: true}) do |ssh|
    puts "Connected";
    puts ssh.exec! "echo Hello";
    ssh.loop(3);
  end'
~/my-project/.vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-7.2.3/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:198:in `block in poll_message':
    disconnected: Too many authentication failures (2) (Net::SSH::Disconnect)
        from ~/my-project/.vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-7.2.3/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:190:in `loop'
        from ~/my-project/.vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-7.2.3/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:190:in `poll_message'
        from ~/my-project/.vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-7.2.3/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:175:in `next_message'
        from ~/my-project/.vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-7.2.3/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:103:in `block in next_message'
        from ~/my-project/.vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-7.2.3/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:102:in `loop'
        from ~/my-project/.vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-7.2.3/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:102:in `next_message'
        from ~/my-project/.vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-7.2.3/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:50:in `authenticate_with_alg'
        from ~/my-project/.vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-7.2.3/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:100:in `block in authenticate_with'
        from ~/my-project/.vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-7.2.3/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:97:in `each'
        from ~/my-project/.vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-7.2.3/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:97:in `authenticate_with'
        from ~/my-project/.vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-7.2.3/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:19:in `block in authenticate'
        from ~/my-project/.vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-7.2.3/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:132:in `block in each_identity'
        from ~/my-project/.vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-7.2.3/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:124:in `each'
        from ~/my-project/.vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-7.2.3/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:124:in `each_identity'
        from ~/my-project/.vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-7.2.3/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:18:in `authenticate'
        from ~/my-project/.vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-7.2.3/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:88:in `block in authenticate'
        from ~/my-project/.vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-7.2.3/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:72:in `each'
        from ~/my-project/.vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-7.2.3/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:72:in `authenticate'
        from ~/my-project/.vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/net-ssh-7.2.3/lib/net/ssh.rb:262:in `start'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'

Running OpenSSH client
$ ssh -oHostname=3.456.789.12 -l ubuntu server.example.com -- echo Hello
Hello

Running Net::SSH without the SSH agent
$ SSH_AUTH_SOCK= bundle exec ruby -rnet/ssh -e 'Net::SSH.start("server.example.com","ubuntu",{
  host_name:"3.456.789.12",
  verify_host_key: :never,
  user_known_hosts_file: "/dev/null",
  non_interactive: true}) do |ssh|
    puts "Connected";
    puts ssh.exec! "echo Hello";
    ssh.loop(3);
  end'
Connected
Hello

Server logs
It gets weirder if we look at the server logs:
This is the OpenSSH client connection:
Jul 03 07:50:44 172-24-51-231.us-east-2.example.com sshd[42437]:
  AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/share/ec2-instance-connect/eic_run_authorized_keys ubuntu SHA256:fMBMXD1mpUpM/vmVcjaXDvdIvPy4GCCdG5lc8ga1cLU failed, status 22
Jul 03 07:50:45 172-24-51-231.us-east-2.example.com sshd[42437]:
  AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/share/ec2-instance-connect/eic_run_authorized_keys ubuntu SHA256:nfsiFP9APVl6oOK5htpldBmknVTDt1lCLvuHpTaaAao failed, status 22
Jul 03 07:50:45 172-24-51-231.us-east-2.example.com sshd[42437]:
  AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/share/ec2-instance-connect/eic_run_authorized_keys ubuntu SHA256:t3+SY5Ru+tJ3r/HE7qIW4fnXswQ16btCiIadVGa2XPM failed, status 22
Jul 03 07:50:45 172-24-51-231.us-east-2.example.com sshd[42437]:
  userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-dss not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
Jul 03 07:50:45 172-24-51-231.us-east-2.example.com sshd[42437]:
  Accepted publickey for ubuntu from 213.546.879.21 port 47034 ssh2: RSA SHA256:6Azd3HzkKpBLJ+zsolTOpksL4XX8aNdGWtprUwRvsoY
Jul 03 07:50:45 172-24-51-231.us-east-2.example.com sshd[42437]:
  pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ubuntu(uid=1000) by (uid=0)

And this is the Net::SSH connection:
Jul 03 07:50:18 172-24-51-231.us-east-2.example.com sshd[42392]:
  AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/share/ec2-instance-connect/eic_run_authorized_keys ubuntu SHA256:fMBMXD1mpUpM/vmVcjaXDvdIvPy4GCCdG5lc8ga1cLU failed, status 22
Jul 03 07:50:18 172-24-51-231.us-east-2.example.com sshd[42392]:
  userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
Jul 03 07:50:18 172-24-51-231.us-east-2.example.com sshd[42392]:
  AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/share/ec2-instance-connect/eic_run_authorized_keys ubuntu SHA256:nfsiFP9APVl6oOK5htpldBmknVTDt1lCLvuHpTaaAao failed, status 22
Jul 03 07:50:19 172-24-51-231.us-east-2.example.com sshd[42392]:
  userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
Jul 03 07:50:19 172-24-51-231.us-east-2.example.com sshd[42392]:
  AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/share/ec2-instance-connect/eic_run_authorized_keys ubuntu SHA256:t3+SY5Ru+tJ3r/HE7qIW4fnXswQ16btCiIadVGa2XPM failed, status 22
Jul 03 07:50:19 172-24-51-231.us-east-2.example.com sshd[42392]:
  userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
Jul 03 07:50:19 172-24-51-231.us-east-2.example.com sshd[42392]:
  error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for ubuntu from 213.546.879.21 port 56414 ssh2 [preauth]
Jul 03 07:50:19 172-24-51-231.us-east-2.example.com sshd[42392]:
  Disconnecting authenticating user ubuntu 213.546.879.21 port 56414: Too many authentication failures [preauth]

So we can see that the 4th key I have in my agent - which is a DSA key that is no longer supported by default on modern servers - is sent by the OpenSSH client and rejected because of PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms and then the 5th public key (from the config file) is accepted. In the case of the Net::SSH client, the 3 RSA keys from the agent - same keys as before - are rejected by PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms and the fourth isn't sent - instead we get error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded after only 3 tries.
I tried to find a configuration option in Net::SSH (or OpenSSH client configuration) that maybe controls some kind of feature (that I don't know exists) where the client tells the server how many authentication attempts to allow - but of course I couldn't find such because it makes no sense.
I of course tries to set the Net::SSH option number_of_password_prompts to something larger than the default of 3 and of course it didn't do anything because that option is for password prompts, which we are not doing at all.
Any idea will be appreciated, TIA!

Key selection is likely different between implementations. Thus, if possible, it's often a much better idea to be explicit which keys to use. With the ssh config (which is also partially read to net/ssh), you can use the IdentitiesOnly option to instruct the client to use only the single specified key. The number of possible authentication attempts is entirely server controlled (it would be useless otherwise).

As can be seen in the logs snippets, both implementations serve the same keys in the same order. Indeed using IdentitiesOnly in the config solves the problem of the key being specified in a config file, but it doesn't solve all problems, for example when I actually do need the key to be served from an agent.

The problem is a bug in Net::SSH - issue 886: for some reason Net::SSH can't figure out which key algorithm to use for RSA keys and is by default configured to try both rsa-sha2-256 (a SHA2 variation) and ssh-rsa (SHA-1 which is now rejected by default SSH server configurations), one after another.
As a result, Net::SSH will attempt to authenticate each RSA public key twice - exhausting the default 6 attempts after only 3 RSA keys.
The current workaround is to use the (undocumented) Net::SSH#start option pubkey_algorithms and set it to ["rsa-sha2-256"] (or some other subset of the default algorithm list, if you intend to support certificate based authentication) - this will prevent Net::SSH from using RSA keys with SHA-1 signatures, breaking these types of keys, if you plan to use them.

Nice find. The change was implemented in 7.1.0 and documented (Changes). It seems the link on the github page leads to 6.0.0-beta, instead of current which is 7.2.3 (Docs)
